# Trying to fetch data from server in windows 8 app

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8, winjs

I'm unable to use web services as i m developing win8 app in javascript. so i want to fetch data from test.php from div="class".

**Code:**

```
WinJS.UI.Pages.define("xhr.html", {
    ready: function (element, options) {

        document.querySelector("#btn1").onclick = function (e) {
            WinJS.xhr({ url: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/test.php?serial=13", responseType: "document" }).then(function (xhr) {

                document.querySelector(".xhr #results1").innerText = xhr.response.querySelector("div[class='garaz']")[2].src;
                //document.querySelector(".xhr #results1").appendChild(imga);
            });
        };
```

**Error:**
Exception is about to be caught by JavaScript library code at line 10, column 21 in ms-appx://694ccf96-9429-4c5a-95ec-bde492c2041a/xhr.js

0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'src' of undefined or null reference

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

---

if my question is stupid please ignore it because i m just learning and if there is an easy way kindly help me do the same thing. its been a month i m stuck at this problem. help

Comment: when i remove src from about code i get reply "undefined" in APP instead of text i have written

Comment: Is there a `src` attribute on the `div` you're using? There wouldn't normally be.

Comment: yes my bad i just reused the code n didnt thought of src.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many `.garaz` elements in the response, then use `querySelectorAll`. And also you can make the selector more simple: `response.querySelectorAll('.garaz')[2].src`

Comment: there is only one div n class. didnt work. error: unable to get property src.

Comment: But then why you are trying to get element at the index `2` (_`querySelector("div[class='garaz']")[2].src`_)?  `querySelector` returns one single element or null!

Comment: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'src' of undefined or null reference

Comment: i get undefined(in app) instead of error when i set [2] to [0] in your code

Comment: You should not use `[SOME_INDEX]` at all, as `querySelector` doesnt return an array. It is single generic NODE: `querySelector('.garaz').src`. And you mentioned your `.garaz` is a DIV Element, is it true? While `src` attribute has only IMG Element. If you though has a DIV, then you should get the attribute via `getAttribute` function: `response.querySelect('.garaz').getAttribute('src')` Cheers

Comment: yes garaz is a div, i copied this example from CODESHOW it was getting microsoft logo from microsoft site. thanks for correcting this problem. 
Now i m getting (in app) "[Object NodeList]" instead of data. i think we are close to solution

Comment: yo man love u it worked 'document.querySelector(".xhr #results1").innerText = xhr.response.querySelector('.garaz').innerText;'

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in query selector section i was using src attribute which is attribute of img tag and was using array . Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/2436109/tenbits

```
document.querySelector(".xhr #results1").innerText = xhr.response.querySelector('.garaz').innerText;
```